# How to check if params[:some][:field] is nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, null

I tried code, that plused a lot of people - [How to test if parameters exist in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629402/how-to-test-if-parameters-exist-in-rails), but it didn't work():

```
     if ( params.has_key?([:start_date]) && params.has_key?([:end_date]) )
```

I think, that is because of complicated params and if I write this:

```
       if ( params.has_key?([:report][:start_date]) && params.has_key?([:report][:end_date]) )
```

gives me error

```
        can't convert Symbol into Integer
```

this doesn't work too:

```
           if ( params[:report][:start_date] && params[:report][:end_date] )
```

gives me error:

```
        undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

It always go into else statement.

Here are my params:

```
    report: 
    start_date: 01/08/2012
    end_date: 10/08/2012
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid NoMethodError for missing elements in nested hashes, without repeated nil checks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371716/how-to-avoid-nomethoderror-for-missing-elements-in-nested-hashes-without-repeat)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
 if params[:report] && params[:report][:start_date] && params[:report][:end_date]
```

Comment: Mikhail Nikalyukin, hello from Lutsk, zemelya)

Comment: Isn't there a more brief and elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 12):

Cross-post answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429790/is-there-a-clean-way-to-avoid-calling-a-method-on-nil-in-a-nested-params-hash/34550819#34550819):

Ruby 2.3.0 makes this very easy to do with [#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig).

```
h = { foo: {bar: {baz: 1}}}

h.dig(:foo, :bar, :baz)           #=> 1
h.dig(:foo, :zot, :baz)           #=> nil
```

Answer (score 7):

I have been looking for a better solution too.  I found this one:

[Is there a clean way to avoid calling a method on nil in a nested params hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429790/is-there-a-clean-way-to-avoid-calling-a-method-on-nil-in-a-nested-params-hash)

```
params[:some].try(:[], :field)
```

You get the value or `nil` if it does not exist.

So I figured let's use `try` a different way:

```
params[:some].try(:has_key?, :field)
```

It's not bad.  You get `nil` vs. `false` if it's not set.  You also get `true` if the param is set to `nil`.

Comment: Note: `try` is a Rails method, not a Ruby method.

Answer (score 6):

It would seem you need the following

```
    params[:report].present?
```

or

```
    params[:report].nil?
```

or

```
    params[:report].empty?
```

depending on what you are trying to check for

Answer (score 1):

This works to:

```
if params[:report].has_key?(:start_date)
```

And maybe add this so you also check if it is not empty:

```
&& !params[:report][:start_date].empty?
```